# get number of levels of a cell

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Well i got the problem, that i have to acces the content of a cell in Matlab. But it's not an ordinary cell. There could be a cell in a cell. And i don't know how many levels the first cell has.

All the cells have the dimension (1,x)

so it could be 
`mycell{cell1{cell11{char1, char2}}, char3, cell2{char4, char5, char6}}`

i have to get the char variables, and i have to know where they are.

this type of cell is returned, when i do this

```
get_param(path_to_busselector, 'Inputsignals')
```

path_to_busselector is the path  to a bus selector in Simulink.

I can hard code it, but then i can only  handle a fixed number of cell-levels, and this is a problem.

My ideas are, that i construct something with a while loop and probably something with the eval command.

here i have an example model [Matlab example model](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5em4ime3unf7kxy/AABffuPblyZKeRe1iRSs9Kbsa?dl=0) and a skript which gives the signals names. if you run the command `signalnames = get_param(BlockPaths(Cellofbusselector))` then there is a cell like i have. now i want to get acces to the signals in the bus selector, but i don't want to do this by hand. If i want to acces the signal in a skript, i have to know the compleete name of the signal. is this clear or am i just unable to tell what i want. sorry if the second statement is true, i will try again

so after i get the name of the signal i can do something like this 
`set_param(outporthandle_of_busselector, 'Outport', fullsignalname)`

and for this i have to know the exact signal name.

Thanks for your time and your ideas

Comment: What would the desired output be? Say a string with all those `chars` contacatenated? Can we assume `char1` etc are each a single character?

Comment: no they are a string of characters. i need the exact name of the signal on the bus, and there can be a nested bus in the bus. the name of the signal is put together with different chars. so the name could be `busname.nestedbusname.signalname` but i don't know how many nested bus systems are nested in each other. thats where the cells in the cells come from.

Comment: So for example `myCell = {'aa', {'bb' 'cccc'}, {'d' 'ee';'ff' 'ggg'}, {'h', {'iii', 'jj'}}}`? Again, what would the desired output be, exactly?

Comment: here i have an example model [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5em4ime3unf7kxy/AABffuPblyZKeRe1iRSs9Kbsa?dl=0) and a skript which gives the signals names. if you run the command `signalnames = get_param(BlockPaths(jj))` then there is a cell like i have. now i want to get acces to the signals in the bus selector, but i don't want to do this by hand. If i want to acces the signal in a skript, i have to know the compleete name of the signal. is this clear or am i just unable to tell what i want. sorry if the second statement is true, i will try again

Comment: sorry it's `signalnames = get_param(BlockPaths(Cellofbusselector))` what you have to run.

Comment: Can you give an input and also show us what output you expect from this input? I assume that you have in mind what you want. If that is not the case, would recursion work badly here? I know Matlab is bad on recursion, but if the amount of data is small, and the function is called only a few times per run it should not be a problem. However for real time programs this will be too slow. Further, **do not write an example input or output in a comment. EDIT the question and write it there. Otherwise it may be closed as unclear what you ask**

Comment: thanks patrik for the hint, about the editing? first it has to work, then i can make it faster. the function will be called when the simulink model is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found a solution. It's not very nice, but it works.

All the files can be downloded [here from dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5em4ime3unf7kxy/AABffuPblyZKeRe1iRSs9Kbsa?dl=0)

Sorry, I would have liked to post an image, but I don't have 10 reputations. So you have to donwload it from the link above.

Here ist the main skript and further down is a recursif function. 
The skript should also work for all other Simulin models with a bus. But just now it just works, if there ist only one busselector. But it is not much to program for several bus systems and bus selectors.

```
    % Name_Signals_after_Blocknames
format compact, clear all, clc

cd(''); % Directory where the simulink model is safed

Simulink_Model = ('linearGuide_model.slx');
Simulink_Model = ('Verbindung.slx');
Simulink_Model = ('bus_system.slx');
% Simulink_Model = ('singlebus.slx');

[path, Model_name, ext] = fileparts(Simulink_Model);

BlockPaths = find_system(Model_name,'LookUnderMasks', 'all' ,'Type','Block');
length_Model_name = length(Model_name);

Cellofbusselector = [];
jj = 0;

for ii = 1:length(BlockPaths)
    disp(BlockPaths{ii})
    porthandles = get_param(BlockPaths{ii}, 'PortHandles');
    outporthandles = get_param(porthandles.Outport, 'Line');

    Block_Name = BlockPaths{ii};

    %     if length(outporthandles) > 1              % only give names to outputs of a subsystem, they are also listed in the BlockPaths cell
    %         warning ('more than one signal wants to get the same name, might be a Subsystem')
    %     else

    if strcmp(BlockPaths{ii}(end-7:end), 'Selector')    % you can not change the name of a line connecting a Bus Selector
        disp('Here we have a Bus selector')
        jj = 1+jj;
        Cellofbusselector(jj) = ii;
    else
        if isempty(outporthandles)
            warning(['Block ', Block_Name, ' has no Output'] )
        elseif length(outporthandles) == 1
            if outporthandles == -1      % outporthanldes == 1, when there is no signal attachet to the outport of the block
                warning(['Block ', Block_Name, ' has no Output-Signal attached'] )
            else
                Signal_name = BlockPaths{ii}((length_Model_name+2):end);
                set_param(outporthandles, 'Name', Signal_name);
            end
        elseif length(outporthandles) > 1
            for jj = 1:length(outporthandles)
                if outporthandles{jj} == -1      % outporthanldes == 1, when there is no signal attachet to the outport of the block
                    Block_Name = BlockPaths{ii};
                    warning(['Block ', Block_Name, ' has no Output-Signal attached'] )
                else
                    Signal_name = [BlockPaths{ii}((length_Model_name+2):end), '_out', num2str(jj)];
                    set_param(outporthandles{jj}, 'Name', Signal_name);
                end
            end
        end
    end
    %     end

end         % for ii = 1:length(BlockPaths)



buscell = get_param(BlockPaths{Cellofbusselector}, 'InputSignals');


[signalname, buslevel, numofsig, busname] = f_get_complete_signalnames(buscell)


%% 

signalnamesize = size(signalname);
for ii = 1:signalnamesize(1)
    for kk = 1:signalnamesize(2)
        if isempty(signalname{ii,kk})
        else 
            nrofbusnames = kk-1;
            fullbusname = '';
            for i = 1:nrofbusnames
                fullbusname = [fullbusname '.' busname{i}];
            end            
            fullsignames{ii,1} = [fullbusname(2:end) '.' signalname{ii,kk}]
        end
    end
end
```

Here is the code from the recursiv function

```
function [signalname, buslevel, numofsig, busname] = f_get_complete_signalnames(buscell, buslevel, numofsig, signalname, busname)
%% Description
% This function returns the complete signal names which are stored in a
% bus. The name looks something like bus1.bus2.signal1. 


if nargin < 2;    buslevel = 1; end
if nargin < 3;    numofsig = 0; end
if nargin < 4;    signalname = {}; end
if nargin < 5;    busname = {}; end


buscellsize = size(buscell);

buscellsize(1);               % busvert is the vertical dimension of buscell
for kk = 1:buscellsize(1)
    if ischar(buscell{kk,1}) && buscellsize(2) == 1
        numofsig = numofsig + 1;
        signalname{numofsig, buslevel} = buscell{kk,1};

    elseif ischar(buscell{kk,1}) && buscellsize(2) == 2
        busname{buslevel-1} = buscell{kk,1};
        [signalname, buslevel, numofsig, busname] = f_get_complete_signalnames(buscell{kk,2}, buslevel, numofsig, signalname, busname);

    elseif iscell(buscell{kk,1}) && buscellsize(2) == 1
        buslevel = buslevel+1;
        [signalname, buslevel, numofsig, busname] = f_get_complete_signalnames(buscell{kk,1}, buslevel, numofsig, signalname, busname);
        buslevel = buslevel-1;
    end
end

end
```

I hope I made this right. And this helps somebody.